# Oracle SQL : Value will be true every after 30 days

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not really good in Oracle SQL but i'm trying to check a date something like this

For example: 01-Jan-2000

How can I check if 30 days passed already, and also for 60 months and so on.
Basically i need to make a condition that will return true after a month and so on. i can check it 1 by 1 but it's obviously not good.

```
DECLARE
appn_date DATE;
BEGIN
appn_date := Trunc(TO_DATE ('10-AUG-2016'));

IF (appn_date = trunc(sysdate) - interval '30' day) THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Yes');

ELSE 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No');

END IF;

END;
```

It should output Yes because 30 days passed already, but it will also output Yes after 60 days, 90 days and so on. I think modulo will work on this. any idea?

Comment: well if 60 months have passed then obviously 30 days had also already passed .. so no need to check for 30 days ..check for last date .. or am i missing your quesrtion >?

Comment: so here's what i'm going to do. I'm going to insert a value every after 30days, so if the date is january 1, i'm going to insert a value in february 1, march 1 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

To check if that column's value is older then 30 days, use:

```
where the_date_column <= sysdate - interval '30' day
```

or a bit shorter but identical

```
where the_date_column <= sysdate - 30
```

For months you need to use `add_months()`

```
where the_date_column <= add_months(sysdate, -60);
```

As Oracle's `DATE` isn't really a "date" but a "datetime" you might need `trunc()` (for both: the date column and `sysdate`) if you don't want to consider the time part.

See the manual for details on how to [specify intervals](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221) and the [available date functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions002.htm#SQLRF20033)

Comment: Thanks man, this is what i'm looking for -

where the_date_column <= sysdate - interval '30' day

Comment: This is applicable for 30days only, how about for 60 days have passed and 90 days? i need to check every 30 days passed.

Comment: If you need to check for 90 days use `- 90`

Comment: I need to check every after 30 days, so 30, 60, 90, 120 and so on. It's obviously not good to define all of them, coz it will be infinite.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you mean. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39952269/edit) your question and the table definition (as `create table`)  some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)